# I am having difficulty pulling from heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, github

I have just been invited on Heroku to participate in a web application. I keep getting this error message when I type in the git clone command.

```
The authenticity of host 'heroku.com (50.19.85.154)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 8b:48:5e:67:0e:c9:16:47:32:f2:87:0c:1f:c8:60:ad.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'heroku.com,50.19.85.154' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Input command:

```
git clone git@heroku.com:stormy-stone-5088.git -o heroku
```

Comment: Are you logged into heroku via console?

Comment: Heroku doesn't know about your private key. Log into heroku via the console like John suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need your private keys set up if not done for other projects (thus often assumed by authors)

Type

`cd ~; ssh-keygen -t dsa

 #(changes directory to home and generate the keys.)`

press return four times, click your heels three times and your keys will be in `~/.ssh`

`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` is your public key, the one you give to other people.